# .Net Windows Forms Should Dispose Method Called If User Control Object Is Not Needed Aynmore

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I've .NET Windows Forms Application. On GUI there is main panel and if user navigate pages i'm adding new User Control object to this panel controls collection. Before adding new one, i was disposing the old one but it causes some problems like another thread running depending on the old user control. I'm disposing them because they have lists, variables and i don't want them to cause unnecessary memory usage. Should I dispose them or Garbage collector can handle with it after i remove old user controls from panel controls collection ?

Comment: _"but it causes some problems like another thread running depending on the old user control"_ Why is the UserControl accessed from another thread in the first place? And why are you trying to dispose of the UserControl if it's still needed? To answer your question: no, the GC will _not_ collect disposable resources. You _should_ call `Dispose()` on the UserControl once it's not needed anymore. Otherwise, it'll remain in memory.

Comment: I'm accessing UserControl from another thread because there is datagridview object and it shows some data and user can search with entering input a textbox. On textbox text change search function is called  and it adds filtered data to datagridview. It can be long proccess so i use threads. While search proccess is continuing user can change the page and it disposes old page

Comment: If you use any threading, you should pass the data to elaborate, not the Controls that show that data, or access any Control from that worker thread. If you use Tasks, you can more easily cancel a Task passing also a CancellationToken.